# REST API with segmented/path ID

Tags: rest

I am trying to design a REST API for a system where the resources are essentially identified by path-like addresses with varying numbers of segments. For example, a "Schema" resource could be represented on the file system as follows:

> /Resources/Schemas/MyFolder2/MyFolder5/MySchema27

The file-system path /Resources/Schemas/ is the root folder for all Schemas, and everything below this is entirely user defined (as far as folder depth and folder naming). So, in the example above, the particular Schema would be uniquely identified by the following address (since "MySchema27" by itself would not necessarily be unique):

> /MyFolder2/MyFolder5/MySchema27

What would be the best way to refer to a resource like this in a REST API?

If I have a /schemas collection my REST URL could be:

> /schemas/MyFolder2/MyFolder5/MySchema27

Would that be a reasonable approach? Are there better ways of handling this?

I could, potentially, do a 2-step approach where the client would first have to search for a Schema using the Schema address (in URL parameters or in the request body), which would then return a unique ID that could then be used with a more traditional /schemas/{id} design. Not sure that I like that, though, especially since it would mean tracking a separate ID for each resource. Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to add a resource to your "folder" `/Resources/Schemas/` is to make a POST request on it with the body of this POST request containing a representation of the resource to add, then the server will take care of finding the next free {id} and and setting the new resource to `/Resources/Schemas/{id}`.

Another approach is to, as you said, make a GET request on `/Resources/Schemas/new` which would return the next free {id}, and then, make a second request PUT directly on `/Resources/Schemas/{id}`. However this second approach is not as secure as the first since two simultaneous request could lead to the same new {id} returned and so the second PUT would erase the first. You can secure this with some sort of reservation mechanism.

Comment: Actually, the only problem which I can think of with your proposition is that we usually use / to express the idea of hierarchy in a URI, so its a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

This is called as Resource Based URI approach for building REST services . Follow  these wonderful set of video tutorials to understand more about them and learn how to implement too . https://javabrains.io/courses/javaee_jaxrs

Comment: Thanks. I did watch some of those videos a while back, and they are very good. However, as I understand it, Resource Based URIs are simply the normal "best practice" way of doing URIs with REST. And I already feel I understand that basic approach. My question, however, is about how to handle multi-part identifiers (rather than the single-part identifiers normally presented in tutorials and the vast majority of real REST APIs I've seen). As far as I can tell, the tutorial you linked just talks about the normal, single-part identifier case. Thanks for taking the time to respond, though.